# Sql - Slow query when fetching records from large table (100M+) using join, tips?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-administration

Working on improving the query below on some large tables (Im using Postgres v12.4):

```
people : 137 Million records
delimiters: 1.2 Million records
person_delimiters: 329 Million records
```

```
SELECT "delimiters".*, "a"."person_id" FROM "delimiters" 
INNER JOIN "person_delimiters" as "a" on "delimiters"."id" = "a"."delimiter_id" 
WHERE ("a"."person_id" IN (SELECT id FROM "people" LIMIT 1000));
```

(the subquery using LIMIT 1000 is here for generic purposes, on its real application though, I get specific sets of 1000 person ids)

`person_delimiters` is an intermediary table that has two columns (`person_id`, `delimiter_id`);

Output from EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
 Hash Join  (cost=46025.12..11207871.13 rows=164750752 width=2346) (actual time=65659.597..66354.997 rows=1044 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (a.delimiter_id = delimiters.id)
   ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=57.96..8456389.56 rows=164750752 width=32) (actual time=20.582..64777.963 rows=1044 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (a.person_id = people.id)
         ->  Seq Scan on person_delimiters a  (cost=0.00..5758538.04 rows=329501504 width=32) (actual time=0.008..30865.854 rows=329501518 loops=1)
         ->  Hash  (cost=45.46..45.46 rows=1000 width=16) (actual time=0.384..0.385 rows=1000 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 55kB
               ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..35.46 rows=1000 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.241 rows=1000 loops=1)
                     ->  Seq Scan on people  (cost=0.00..4888821.40 rows=137873840 width=16) (actual time=0.003..0.158 rows=1000 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=24508.85..24508.85 rows=71385 width=2330) (actual time=839.841..839.841 rows=1227076 loops=1)
         Buckets: 2048  Batches: 64  Memory Usage: 3015kB
         ->  Seq Scan on delimiters  (cost=0.00..24508.85 rows=71385 width=2330) (actual time=0.007..303.814 rows=1227076 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 1.197 ms
 Execution Time: 66355.110 ms
```

Indexes:

```
-- person_delimiters --
 public     | person_delimiters | person_delimiters_pkey                       |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX person_delimiters_pkey ON public.person_delimiters USING btree (
person_id, delimiter_id)
 public     | person_delimiters | idx_person_delimiters_delimiter_id_person_id |            | CREATE INDEX idx_person_delimiters_delimiter_id_person_id ON public.person_delimiter
s USING btree (delimiter_id, person_id)

-- people -- 
 public     | people    | people_two_pkey                            |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX people_pkey ON public.people USING btree (id)

-- delimiters -- 
 public     | delimiters | delimiters_pkey                            |            | CREATE UNIQUE INDEX delimiters_pkey ON public.delimiters USING btree (id)
```

Anything I could work on, to optimize it?

Comment: For a simple seq scan on `delimiters` with no filters, there is no good reason for the row estimate to be off by so much.  Does an ANALYZE on the table (or VACUUM ANALYZE, because why not?) fix this estimation problem?  If so, does it fix the entire problem?

Comment: Will try it out @jjanes! Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

it normally works best to start off with the smallest possible table/dataset and then work up from there. The following is probably the most efficient way of approaching the problem in SQL (the 2nd CTE is really there to clarify the approach - you could probably move the logic into the main select statement without affecting much).

If this doesn't improve the performance significantly then you are probably looking at indexing/partitioning/temporary table solutions.

```
with person_id_list as 
(
    SELECT id FROM people LIMIT 1000
),
person_delim_list as 
(
    SELECT pd.delimiter_id, pd.person_id
    FROM person_id_list pil
    INNER JOIN person_delimiters pd on pil.id = pd.person_id
)
SELECT D.*, pdl.person_id
FROM person_delim_list pdl
INNER JOIN delimiters d on pdl.delimiter_id = d.id
```